# как понять i < array.length - 1 ? менял в задаче условие i<array.length результат на выходе был тот же

Tags: javascript

```
    function findDublicates(array) {
        let result = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {

            const current = array[i];
```

Comment: Прочитать в книге по циклам. Что тут понимать если в каждом учебнике для новичков написано?

Comment: _результат на выходе был тот же_ - почему ты так думаешь? Что для тебя является результатом? Как ты проверял?

Comment: это уже решённая задача с ответом . Вот я на ответ и смотрю = он не меняется . как проверить по другому - я не знаю.

Comment: Во-первых вопрос значит должен звучать по-другому, не "как понять N", а "почему результат не меняется при изменении параметров" или подобное, во-вторых, чтобы получить ответ нужно постараться и приложить усилия на написание чётко сформулированного вопроса. Вот сейчас в нём нет ни входных данных, ни результата применения функции, ни ожидания от неё, ни того, что в итоге получаешь, никакого описания почему ты ожидаешь то, что ожидаешь

Answer (score 1):

```
 function findDublicates(array) { //в функцию findDublicates передается array.
        let result = []; //создается массив result

        for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) { //запускается цикл

            const current = array[i]; //создается постоянная current и ей присваивается i-й элемент array
```

Comment: пробовал менять  array.length - 1 на  просто array.length , ничего не меняется . в чём тогда смысл записи ?